# Pop up window of Code::bloks on Windows 10

Tags: c++, opencv

I'm learning OpenCV on Windows and I am using Code::bloks. When I call the funciotion of imshow() it will show a pop up window where is the image. The problem is that I can't zoon this windows so I can't see pixels values.

Comment: AFAIK, zoom functionality for imshow window is something you have to implement yourself. However, it's being a long time since I last used opencv so things may be different now.

Answer (score 1):

You can't zoom in an OpenCV default Window, this is not functionality built into the core OpenCV libraries

You can however build this functionality yourself, especially if you build using Qt. Here is [an example](https://github.com/delmottea/QtOpenCVWidget)

Comment: But some friends of mine have ubuntu and on that by zooming the OpenCV default Window, it appears the value of pixels